# How to use rangeOfString below in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I have a string "10.9.1.1", I want to get substring "10.9". How can I achieve this?
So far I have the following:

```
var str = "10.9.1.1"
let range = str.rangeOfString(".",options: .RegularExpressionSearch)!
let rangeOfDecimal = Range(start:str.startIndex,end:range.endIndex)
var subStr = str.subStringWithRange(rangeOfDecimal)
```

But this will only return 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code returns "1" only, because "." in a regular
expression pattern matches any character.

The correct pattern would be

```
\d+    one ore more digits
\.     a literal dot
\d+    one or more digits
```

In a Swift string, you have to escape the backslashes as `"\\"`:

```
let str = "10.9.1.1"
if let range = str.rangeOfString("\\d+\\.\\d+",options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    let subStr = str.substringWithRange(range)
    println(subStr) // "10.9"
}
```

Comment: thanks, it was the regular expressions part that was bugging me!